# Can we edit users profile using LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there a way to update the linked in users profile using the linked in api. i need to have this option for my application. Can anyone please tell is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is classified as too broad, i think it's because of the title, i have changed the title now. Does it still looks like too broad ??

Comment: I think that was a big part of it - this is more specific, and I've re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Profile Edit functionality available for the Open Program in the LinkedIn API.

Comment: Hi Kirsten, Thanks for the response. Is there a way to upload the resume using the LinkedIn API?

Comment: No, the website has this functionality but the API does not yet support this.